# Microsoft word. Can I populate fields in one document from another?

Tags: microsoft-word

I have a 'terms_of_reference' word document I send to clients (schools as it happens).  It has a range of fields for 'School name', 'Contact teacher', 'Dates' and so on. When I work with a new school I update the fields, let the document populate itself and print (or in this case, pdf and email) a version for the school.

After the project at the school finishes I prepare a press_release for the school so they can send it to local papers and so on. Much of the information in the press_release  'School name', 'Contact teacher', 'Dates' is the same as in the terms_of_reference.

Is it possible to write a template in such a way that you can say "Rather than asking me for each field when this updates, ask me for the document where I can find the original field values".

If it isn't possible, is this a problem that is solved in a different way?

Answer (score 0):

You could use Word's Mail Merge Functionality to accomplish this. I did a google search:  "mail merge excel to word"  the top result currently reveals this link

https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Mail-merge-using-an-Excel-spreadsheet-858c7d7f-5cc0-4ba1-9a7b-0a948fa3d7d3

I could copy and paste the information from that site to here, but just like the link that will grow stale, so too, will the information.  When the link goes dead so does the information, because they've moved on to a new version of the product.

Personally, I would use SQL Server and make an SSRS report instead, though, so the data could be more easily leveraged for other reporting.

Comment: External links can break, in which case your solution would not be available.  It's better to include the essential information within your answer and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: @phipywr You should take the advice and do it now for this answer, otherwise it may be deleted as link-only if it is reviewed.

Comment: The correct answer IMO is: do a simple google search to find the current method to accomplish this, but I didn't want to be rude. If my answer is deleted, then I think the question should be too because this site is called "superuser."  Most responders here seem offended by people who don't RTFM.  I think this person is relatively new to technology so I'm trying to nicely push them to look for their own solution.